# How to print the next line of a match in Perl?

Tags: perl

So, I wrote a script which calculates the factorials of 4^(0) to 4^(10) as I wanted to test the run-times, and I also wanted to compare Stirling's approximation with the with the actual number of digits of the respective factorials.

So I have a file with this data called factorials.txt
which contains the following data for example:

```
The factorial of 1 is
1
The factorial of 4 is
24
The factorial of 16 is
20922789888000
The factorial of 64 is
126886932185884164103433389335161480802865516174545192198801894375214704230400000000000000
```

I would like the output of the factorials to be the following:

```
Factorial 1: 1 digits.

Factorial 4: 2 digits.

Factorial 16: 14 digits.

Factorial 64: 90 digits
```

I was able to write a script to get these values, where after my statement for the factorial of ___ is ... on the next line is the value of the factorial. But I wasn't able to select the next line after the match, so I wrote this much using a while loop through the file matching for the nonexistence of letters, and then printing the length of the characters on the line. It works, but I don't think that it's very efficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file = 'factorials.txt';
my $filehandle;
open($filehandle, '<', $file) or die "Could not open file $_ because $!";

while(my $line = <$filehandle>)
{
chomp $line;
my $index = $.;
        if($line !~ m/[a-z]/)
        {
                say length($line);
        }

}
```

My script outputs the following, for example:

```
1
2
14
90
```

I want the parsing script to if it matches the word "factorial" on the line, print the length of characters on the next line. I believe this must be possible, but I can't seem to figure out how to go to the next line.

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: What do you need `$index` for?

Comment: I thought it might be useful because the $index which is the special variable "$." contains the line number. So if I printed if($index == 2){say $line;}, it would print line 2 with a newline. But I can't figure out how to increment the index according to the line it matches on.

Comment: I am not sure I get it -- do you want to process the file shown in the beginning, so to append the number of digits to the `factorial of N is` line, but keep the following line with the result?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: You've just answer @zdim's _either or_ question with yes. :D

Comment: @simbabque  My bad, I edited the comment ... :))) ... editing it _back to what it was_ ... done.  All good now :)

Comment: Oh wow, I answered the either or question with a "Yes." That's embarrassing.

Comment: No, no, you didn't -- you answered my question when it didn't have the `or` part (so it was yes/no), and _then_ I edited that comment, making it either/or (having not seen your answer at that time).  Now I put it back to what it had been and your answer is spot on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole thing can be much simpler than that. All you need is one specific match.

The following code will check for the text with the number that you've built the factorial of. If it finds that, it `print`s the label. It does that by capturing the number into `$1`. The `print` does not have a line break.

If it doesn't find it, it assumes the whole line is the one with the factorial, so it `say`s the `length` of the line. This will now have the line break, and the next output will go to the next line.

The `chomp` is important for the `length` to work correctly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ m/factorial of ([0-9]+)/) {
        print "Factorial of $1: ";
    } else {
        say length $line;
    }
}

__DATA__
The factorial of 1 is
1
The factorial of 4 is
24
The factorial of 16 is
20922789888000
The factorial of 64 is
126886932185884164103433389335161480802865516174545192198801894375214704230400000000000000
```

And the output:

```
Factorial of 1: 1
Factorial of 4: 2
Factorial of 16: 14
Factorial of 64: 90
```

Comment: Apparently we need to also reprint the line with the result (so to add `say $line;` in `else`)

Comment: Maybe I'm having a hard time communicating what I'm trying to say. However, simbabque has provided the expected result as shown in my question which is good.

Comment: That is an interesting way of doing things, simbabque.

Comment: @xyz123 I think you're trying to say it with too many words. A lot of the background in your question is not relevant. You have some data, and you want to transform it. It doesn't really matter where it's from. ;)

Comment: @xyz123 well, it's pragmatic. The alternative would be to save the most recent number in a variable, but since you don't need it for anything but printing, you can just print right away. If you were to use it as a hash key that'd be a different story...